# hazelcast for tomcat session replication: sticky

Tags: hazelcast, tomcat9, session-replication

Hazelcast tomcat session manager:

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-tomcat-sessionmanager

```
Sticky Sessions (default)

Sticky Sessions are used to improve the 
performance since the sessions do not
move around the cluster.

Requests always go to the same instance 
where the session was firstly created. 
By using a sticky session, you mostly 
eliminate session replication problems,
except for the failover cases. In case
of failovers, Hazelcast helps you to not
lose existing sessions.
```

For P2P, is session replicated in all tomcat instances? or session data is stored in one hazelcast instance?

For sticky=true, no session replication. How not to lose existing sessions in case of failover?

Comment: Should all be trivial to try out and make sure the system behaves as you expect once you've set up everything. E.g. I strongly recommend to run tests, so that there is no mismatch due to any (grammatical or other) misunderstanding